# Unable to create event using microsoft graph api explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, graph-api-explorer

I have necessary permissions to create event via Microsoft Graph API, Via graph API explorer I am trying to create the event. API gives successful response. But in outlook I am getting email delivery failed
What can be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a developer tenant?

Comment: Yes, I have developer tenant